# Prisma updates the master database in SQL Server instead of the database I specify in the connection string

Tags: javascript, sql-server, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm using the t3 stack with prisma and SQL Server. I have my models defined and I'm migrating from SQLite to SQL Server.

When I run

```
npx prisma migrate dev
npx prisma db push
```

prisma is updating my master database instead of the database I specified in the connection string. I'm not getting any errors thrown.

My database url looks like the following:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;initialCatalog={MyDatabase};integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
```

I noticed the tables in my generated migration file use dbo instead of the database name.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCode] (
    [id] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    [userId] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    [zipcode] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [ZipCode_pkey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id]),
    CONSTRAINT [ZipCode_userId_key] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([userId])
);
```

Is there a way to get it to push updates to MyDatabase? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In [some parts of the prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sql-server#connection-details) it uses the connection properties `initial catalog` and `initialCatalog` interchangeably. Have you tried using the `database` property instead?

Comment: I've tried database and initialCatalog, but not initial catalog. I can try that

Comment: I think initial catalog actually worked

Comment: btw, "dbo" is not database, it's schema (db owner), which is the default schema tables have. Database name goes before schema, like: create table MyDatabase.dbo.Zipcode

Answer (score 0):

Based on the correct comment of @AlwaysLearning it turns out that it should be `initial catalog=myDbName` (space between `initial` & `catalog`) and only then it the initial catalog is actually taken into account.